# create editable cshtml View Page in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have following cshtml view page with div sections

```
@model IEnumerable<int>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Template";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create a Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Bank Brochure</div>
    <div>Solution by ggg.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make this cshtml page div sections editable ,how can I do this

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by _Editable!!_??

Comment: I should be able to edit content above div section's inside text

Comment: if i understood correctly  you can to this with a text filed  like `textbox` or `textarea`

Comment: use textarea or  use div with contenteditable='true'

Comment: @Arjun I think contenteditable='true' will be match, can I have an example

Comment: @kez, Whether your issue is fixed or not ?

Comment: @Arjun yeah thats very good fair answer, thanks

Comment: @Arjun now I have requirement like this , could you able to assist me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475288/editable-cshtml-view-page-save-as-pdf/33475632#33475632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May it will helps you

```js
$('#button').on('click',function(){
  
    
    $('#divvalue').html($('#editableddiv').text());
    
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='button' value='Get Div value' /> 
<div> div value : <div id='divvalue'></div> </div>

<div id='editableddiv' contentEditable='True' style='Height:200px; width:200px;border:1px solid'>

  Editable Div
  
</div>
```

**Update:**

To get the editable div value in JQuery and JavaScript

```
var div_value = $('#editableddiv').text();

var div_value = document.getElementById('editableddiv').innerHTML;
```

Comment: IF I want to save that edited div content , will I able to use the approach you suggested ?

Comment: @kez yes you can save the edited div content. using javascript or jquery.verify updated post

Comment: How to direct to POST method save whole View page(after edited) without sending one by one ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific.

if *'Editable'* means *Html Editable*, you can consider using an opensource WYSIWYG editor instance like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

If you want to just show your content normally, but want to make that *div editable*, you can use the `contenteditable="true"` attribute for your div:

```
<div class="someClass" id="someId" contenteditable="true"> ... </div>
```

If all you want is to provide an *editable text area*, you can use MVC's helper functions to do that:

```
<div class="someClass">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.YourModelProperty)
</div>
```

You can check the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.textareafor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to see how to properly use this.

Comment: can I use this WYSIWYG editor for this purpose https://github.com/summernote/summernote ??