# Editable cshtml View Page save as PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razorpdf

I'm trying to create web application that consisting an

1. editable cshtml view page

and then

2. save that edited content **as a PDF** once I click the button

So this is the whole cshtml view page ,

```
        @model IEnumerable<int>

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Create Template";
        }
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Create a Template</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                    <div id='template'>
                       <h1 contentEditable='True'>Product Name</h1>
                        <div >
                          <h2 contentEditable='True'>Product Description</h2>       
                          <p contentEditable='True'>London is the capital city of England.</p>
                       </div>
                   </div>

          <button id="btn_sumbit" type="button" class="btn btn-danger submit">Save as PDF</button>

        </body>
        </html>

        @section Scripts {

            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $('#btn_sumbit').on('click', function () {

                    var div_value = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;

                    RazorPDF.PdfResult(div_value, "PDF");
                });

            </script>

        }
```

I'm using [RazorPDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF) to do this task , but once I click this button it doesn't saving to PDF

I can edit this cshtml view page , I want to save that finally edited content as pdf (which is dynamic view)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing it wrong. The line "RazorPDF.PdfResult(...)" belongs in the Controller not in the View.

Watch this Video: http://nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF 
It should give you a clearer understanding of how things work in RazorPDF.

EDIT:

Just create a Controller method, that generates a PDF-View based on Parameters.

```
public ActionResult Pdf(string name, string description) {
    var product = new Product();
    product.Name = name;
    product.Description = description;

    var pdfResult = new PdfResult(product, "Pdf");

    return pdfResult;
}
```

Of course you need to create a Product-Class that holds the information.

In your Javascript part you can write:

```
location.href = @Url.Action("Pdf", "Controllername") + "?name=" + name + "&description=" + description;
```

This will hopefully generate a link that you can follow in Javascript. name and description are Javascript variables that hold the information that was typed by the user.

Do you understand? My approach would be to generate the PDF content in a different view (like in that video) based on the information of your editable view.

Tell me if it worked. ;-)

Comment: how to trigger that inside the script then ?

Comment: how to trigger that converting to PDF method inside the script then ?

Comment: Use an Ajax-Call to a controller method. Try to reconsider your design. Call a PDF-Method like in that video from Javascript. Give that PDF-Method parameters that tell it how the PDF should look like. And most important of all: google and think first, before asking more questions. SO's aim is not to replace google.

Comment: but in that video he is generating results from controller method then he's extracting those details to PDF, in my context , I can edit this cshtml view page , I want to save that finally edited content as pdf (which is dynamic view)