# How to update user's details in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application written in C#. I have added new variables to the registration page such as, **"FirstName"**, and **"LastName"** which are stored in the AspNetUsers table.

I have created a profile page where users can view these details but I want to let users edit and update these details. I looked at the "ChangePassword" task within the ManageController, but this does not seem to translate for other variables.

How can I let a user change these variables once they have regsitered?

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430083/create-editable-cshtml-view-page-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a view model to handle the data:

```
class ProfileViewModel {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

Then in your `ManageController` you can do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUser(ProfileViewModel model) {
    //get current user and update
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    user.LastName = model.LastName;

    var updateResult = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    if (updateResult.Succeeded) {
        //do something and return
    }
    //failed - do something else and return
}
```